# Jquery slider next/previous buttons

Tags: jquery, slider, addclass, removeclass, appendto

I've built a slider where I can click the images and it moves forward. I'm am trying to add Next and Previous buttons but am having trouble. Any help is appreciated!

Here is a demo of where I am...
[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/coltanious/dRGKH/11/)

```
<div id="container">

    <div class="next">Next</div>
    <div class="prev">Previous</div>

    <div id="image1" class="box">Orange</div>
    <div id="image2" class="box">Blue</div>
    <div id="image3" class="box">Green</div>
    <div id="image4" class="box">Red</div>
    <div id="image5" class="box">Yellow</div>

</div>
```

CSS

```
body {
    padding: 0px;    
}

.next {
    width:100px;
    height:50px;
}

.prev {
    width:100px;
    height:50px;
}

#container {
    position: absolute;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;

}

.box {
    position: absolute;
    width: 50%;
    height: 300px;
    line-height: 300px;
    font-size: 50px;
    text-align: center;
    left: 150%;
    top: 100px;
    margin-left: -25%;
}

#image1 {
    background-color: orange;
    left: 50%;
}

#image2 {
    background-color: blue;
}

#image3 {
    background-color: green;
}

#image4 {
    background-color: red;
}

#image5 {
    background-color: yellow;
}
```

JQUERY

```
$('.box').click(function() {

$(this).animate({
    left: '-50%'
}, 500, function() {
    $(this).css('left', '150%');
    $(this).appendTo('#container');
});

$(this).next().animate({
    left: '50%'
}, 500);
});​
```

​

Answer (score 2):

Hey Check this one out: http://jsfiddle.net/Dwxfc/

This should fit your need,`:)` also note the above sample only have the next functionality hence it repeats itself.

Rest hope it fits your need, please lemme know if this doesn't. `B-)`

**Code**

```
$(function(){

    //Lazyload function
    $.fn.lazyload = function(){
        var image = $(this);
        if (image.attr('real-src')){
            image.attr('src', image.attr('real-src'));
            image.removeAttr('real-src');
        }
        return this;
    };

    //Slider constructor
    $.fn.imageSlider = function(){
        this.each(function(){
            var $slider = $(this);

            var $active = $slider.find('img:first');
            $active.addClass('active');
            $active.lazyload();

            //Slider control buttons
            var $nextButton = $slider.find('.next');
            var $prevButton = $slider.find('.previous');

            $prevButton.toggle();

            //Handle if next button should appear
            $nextButton.click(function(){
                var $next = $active.next();
                $active.removeClass('active');
                $next.addClass('active');
                $active = $next;
                $active.lazyload();

                if ($active.next().length == 0){
                    $nextButton.toggle();
                }
                $prevButton.show();

            })

            //Handle if next button should appear
            $prevButton.click(function(){
                var $prev = $active.prev();
                $active.removeClass('active');
                $prev.addClass('active');
                $active = $prev;
                $active.lazyload();

                if ($active.prev().length == 0){
                    $prevButton.toggle();
                }
                $nextButton.show();
            })
        })

            return this;
        };

})

$(document).ready(function(){
    var $slider = $('#slider');
    if ($slider.find('.active').length == 0){
        $slider.imageSlider();
    }
})
​
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="slider" class="slider_container">
    <center>
        <a href="#" class="previous"> Previous &lt; </a>
        <a href="#" class="next"> Next &gt; </a>
        <img class="slider_image" src="http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/lazyload/img/grey.gif" real-src="http://ultradownloads.com.br/conteudo/Joyce/para_nossa_alegria_cartoon.jpg">
        <img class="slider_image" src="http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/lazyload/img/grey.gif" real-src="http://www.oesquema.com.br/trabalhosujo/wp-content/uploads/2012/03/para-nossa-alegria-pan.jpg">
        <img class="slider_image" src="http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/lazyload/img/grey.gif" real-src="http://youpix.com.br/wp-content/uploads/2012/03/para-nossa-alegria-uhu.jpg">
        <img class="slider_image" src="http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/lazyload/img/grey.gif" real-src="http://2.bp.blogspot.com/-dcgzVluf0is/T2z1K0GbVgI/AAAAAAAAMIU/yVXoH4IHV5M/s1600/para-nossa-alegria.jpg">
        <img class="slider_image" src="http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/lazyload/img/grey.gif" real-src="http://desordempublica.com.br/wp-content/uploads/2012/03/sexta-para-nossa-alegria.jpg">
    </center>
</div>

​
```

**CSS**

```
.slider_container {
    position: relative;
}

.slider_container img {
    display:none;
}

.slider_container img.active {
    display:block;
}
​
```

Comment: Thank you for the response. However, I'm trying to retain the slide effect where the image comes from off the screen. I've been able to get it this far, however, am having trouble getting one image to slide at a time... Take a look here: http://jsfiddle.net/coltanious/dRGKH/

Comment: @WoolfFaulkner cooleos man will get back to you on this effect issue, in the mean time keep playing around it should be straight fwd, `:)`