# Elastic Slider Next/ Prev button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, slideshow

Is it possible to add a *next* and a *prev* button to an elastic [slideshow](http://tympanus.net/Tutorials/ElasticSlideshow/)?

Comment: it is possible, but requires extra coding. if you don't have time to do it, you can use Nivo Slider

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are some jquery plugins for sliders..

Some of these have already prev and next buttons.

http://www.designyourway.net/blog/resources/28-useful-jquery-sliders-you-need-to-download/

How to Create Your Own jQuery Content Slider

http://fearlessflyer.com/2010/08/how-to-create-your-own-jquery-content-slider/

If you build your own prev and next button, these post will help you:

[Jquery slider next/previous buttons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11836681/jquery-slider-next-previous-buttons)